# Compile CUDA code in linux, get error: cutil_inline.h: No such file or directory

Tags: linux, path, cuda

The code was developed in windows,  but when I compile the code under linux with `nvcc`, it gave the  error:

> cutil_inline.h: No such file or directory.

The `PATH` in my machine is :

```
# User specific aliases and functions

export PATH=/usr/local/cuda/bin:/usr/local/NVIDIA_GPU_Computing_SDK:$PATH

export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/cuda/lib64:/usr/local/NVIDIA_GPU_Computing_SDK:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH
```

The missing file `cutil_inline.h` is already in the package "NVIDIA_GPU_Computing_SDK".

How can I solve this problem?

Your kindly reply will be great important to me.

Answer (score 1):

The `PATH` and `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` environment variables are not applicable here.  You will need to modify your linux compile command (with `nvcc`) to include a compiler switch telling the compiler where to find the `cutil_inline.h` file:

```
nvcc -I/path/to/cutil_inline.h/file (....remainder of compile command line)
```

It's likely that you may also have to specify other include path (`-I`) switches as well as library and library path switches (`-l` and `-L`) to tell the linker where to find the appropriate cutil libraries.  (The `PATH` and `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` don't apply here either.)  You may wish to look at the make files included with some of the CUDA samples to see how the relevant cutil header files and libraries are properly referenced.

Comment: Hi Robert Crovella,thanks for your kindly reply.I used the command of " nvcc -I/path/to/cutil_inline.h/file lbm.cu -lm",but get the same error as "cutil_inline.h: No such file or directory." Was

Comment: That path I gave was a bogus path.  You are supposed to put the correct directory path in there.  Please *edit your question* to show: 1. The complete `nvcc` command line you are currently using <and> 2. The full directory path to the `cutil_inline.h`file

Comment: 1.nvcc -arch=sm_20 lbm.cu -o main 2./usr/local/NVIDIA_GPU_Computing_SDK/C/common/inc/cutil_inline.h

Comment: then use this nvcc command line: `nvcc -arch=sm_20 -I/usr/local/NVIDIA_GPU_Computing_SDK/C/common/inc lbm.cu -o main`  And as I mentioned, you will likely have to include some additional switches like `-L/usr/local/NVIDIA_GPU_Computing_SDK/C/common/lib -lcutil` or something like that.

Comment: [fanshiwei@meresgpu mrt_lbm_gpu]$ nvcc lbm.cu -I/usr/local/NVIDIA_GPU_Computing
_SDK/CUDALibraries/common/inc -lm
In file included from lbm.cu:15:
lbm_kernel.h:52:8: warning: extra tokens at end of #endif directive
/usr/local/NVIDIA_GPU_Computing_SDK/CUDALibraries/common/inc/cutil_inline_runtime.h(329): error: identifier "CURAND_STATUS_DOUBLE_PRECISION_REQUIRED" is undefined

Comment: lbm.cu(211): warning: variable "A1" was set but never used
lbm.cu(212): warning: variable "fun" was declared but never referenced
lbm.cu(212): warning: variable "fun1" was declared but never referenced
lbm.cu(212): warning: variable "fun2" was declared but never referenced
lbm.cu(212): warning: variable "rho" was declared but never referenced
lbm.cu(212): warning: variable "rho1" was declared but never referenced
"/tmp/tmpxft_00004b49_00000000-4_lbm.cpp1.ii".

Comment: lbm.cu(212): warning: variable "rho2" was declared but never referenced 1 error detected in the compilation  of  "/tmp/tmpxft_00004b49_00000000-4_lbm.cpp1.ii".

Comment: The first warning about"lbm_kernel.h:52:8: warning: extra tokens at end of #endif directive" the content is "#endif __LBM_KERNEL_H_" How can I correct it.

Comment: These are other issues besides what you are asking about in the original question.  It's difficult to sort out questions like this in the comments stream.  Please either ask **NEW** SO questions to sort these out, or **EDIT YOUR ORIGINAL QUESTION** with the new information or questions you wish to share.

Comment: And what caused the error "1 error detected in the compilation of "/tmp/tmpxft_00004b49_00000000-4_lbm.cpp1.ii"."? I'm warry too much

Comment: The error message is explanatory: `error: identifier "CURAND_STATUS_DOUBLE_PRECISION_REQUIRED" is undefined`   Beyond that, you've not posted any of your code or told us anything about it, so it's difficult to add any comments beyond that.  Please discontinue this and post new questions.  I don't plan to respond to further, new questions posted here.

Comment: Ok.Thanks very much.I will ask New.